# Custom email for Web App on Azure

Tags: email, azure

Is it possible to have a custom email (name@mycustomdomin.com) if I have a Web App hosted in Microsoft Azure? (mycustomdomain.com) If it is, how can I set it up?

I found [this](https://jptacek.com/2013/02/setting-up-email-for-a-custom-domain-on-a-windows-azure-hosted-website/) article, but Custom Domains service no longer run.

It is strange that this isn't native in Azure, because every provider gives you email included in a webhosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure does not include any email service so you must use Office 365 or a 3rd party service.

Comment: Thank you, I set it up using Office 365 and it was pretty easy.